# Inside foreach() function the DIV is overlapping each other

Tags: php, html, css

I have a foreach() function written inside which there is a DIV container showing colors. Its working fine but they are overlapping each other. How can I make this appear side by side with some gap say 10 pixels.

Here is the code

```
<?php foreach($mbs_colors as $color){ ?>
   <div class="membership-indicator" style="background: <?php echo $color; ?>; margin-top: 4px;"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

I also tried the following code but it only separates all from the 1st element and 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc overlaps each other making it visual appearance of only two elements.

```
<?php $j = 0; foreach($mbs_colors as $color){ ?>
   <div class="membership-indicator" style="background: <?php echo $color; ?>; margin-top: 4px; <?php if($j++ != 0){ echo "margin-left: 15px"; } ?>"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

An example is here of what I exactly want to do.

[image]

CSS

```
.membership-indicator {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: What does the class `.membership-indicator` do?

Comment: Please post the generated HTML and CSS in a [mcve] There is no jQuery here

Comment: What does this have to do with `javascript` or `jquery`?

Comment: @Halcyon it holds the colors in square boxes which represents different memberships.

Comment: `div`'s default display is `block`, if you want them side-by-side you should make them display `inline-block`. Also you need some sort or dimensions or content in your div to give it a height and width. You should add the css styles for `.membership-indicator`

Comment: @Halcyon I have added an example at the last. Please see,

Comment: this is Really not a PHP question. Please click `<>` and post RENDERED HTML and the relevant CSS

Comment: as zgood already said you must set the diplay to inline-block. If your div has no content, you also need to set its dimensions. A div element that looks similar to those on your image have a style like this: `display:inline-block; width:15px; height:15px; margin-right:5px;`

Comment: position should be relative @ShubhamJha

Comment: I added the CSS for .membership-indicator plz see

Comment: @ShubhamJha `position: absolute` is definitely a problem, make it `relative` or `static`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `display` property to `inline-block`

```css
.membership-indicator{
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="membership-indicator" style="background: red; margin-top: 4px;"></div>
<div class="membership-indicator" style="background: red; margin-top: 4px;"></div>
<div class="membership-indicator" style="background: red; margin-top: 4px;"></div>
<div class="membership-indicator" style="background: red; margin-top: 4px;"></div>
<div class="membership-indicator" style="background: red; margin-top: 4px;"></div>
<div class="membership-indicator" style="background: red; margin-top: 4px;"></div>
<div class="membership-indicator" style="background: red; margin-top: 4px;"></div>
<div class="membership-indicator" style="background: red; margin-top: 4px;"></div>
<div class="membership-indicator" style="background: red; margin-top: 4px;"></div>
<div class="membership-indicator" style="background: red; margin-top: 4px;"></div>
<div class="membership-indicator" style="background: red; margin-top: 4px;"></div>
<div class="membership-indicator" style="background: red; margin-top: 4px;"></div>
<div class="membership-indicator" style="background: red; margin-top: 4px;"></div>
<div class="membership-indicator" style="background: red; margin-top: 4px;"></div>
<div class="membership-indicator" style="background: red; margin-top: 4px;"></div>
<div class="membership-indicator" style="background: red; margin-top: 4px;"></div>
<div class="membership-indicator" style="background: red; margin-top: 4px;"></div>
<div class="membership-indicator" style="background: red; margin-top: 4px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css.

```
.membership-indicator {
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -10px;
}
```

Comment: but however I am going  with answer by @Luis felipe De jesus Munoz... It did the job better :)